# Issue with dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select

I have two sets of query, one works fine and the other doesn't:

The query that did not work:

```
select * 
from statusreport 
where START_DATE_TIME >= '2019-03-01 00:00:00.000' 
  and START_DATE_TIME < '2019-03-05 00:00:00.000'
```

The query is non responsive. No results obtained and query is in running state forever.

The query that worked:

```
select * 
from statusreport 
where START_DATE_TIME >= '2019-02-20 00:00:00.000' 
  and START_DATE_TIME < '2019-03-05 00:00:00.000'
```

When I was helpless, I started going back on the start date, and whoa I got the query giving some result.

This doesn't make any sense at-least to me. There are not much records too. I hardly have 2k rows out of which some 200 would match the query 1 I have mentioned above.

What could be the reason for this behavior ? Am I missing something important?

Comment: You should compare both execution plans. If you have an index on START_DATE_TIME it could be used in the first case because of out-of-date statistics: server could think there is no rows / very few rows for this interval, and used nested loops (non-clustered index seek + lookups). In the second case it could choose table scan

Comment: Can you try using Between syntax? They are equivalent because the engine converts the between statement in your format.

Comment: Also, if you have an index on the start_date_time column, it might be corrupted and you might need to reach create it.

Comment: "Between" wil not produce equivalent as the query now does not comprend the day 2019-03-05, and between will produce the result with 2019-03-05 00:00:00 included. In any case the problem is not here

Comment: @Yutha Please paste your plans here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and update your questions with the links to both plans

Comment: The small number of rows you mention should run instantly even without the use of indexes. Is statusreport a table? Or is it a super complex view which performs aggregate calculations over millions of joined rows in order to reach the seemingly little 2k rows you mention?

Comment: @Norcino With `DATETIME` it is quite dangerous to use `BETWEEN`. You might [read this *bad habit to kick* by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: A pending (uncomitted) transaction in another session?

Comment: Is this still reproducible? If no, then perhaps pending transaction, like Schnugo mentioned, or something else was blocking execution, for instance, auto stats  update

Comment: I tried using BETWEEN syntax and the behaviour was same.

Comment: What worries me is that why the query returns results to a date range which is say 15 days and not for the range less than that . I am using SQL Server Express edition. Could this be a business trick to force me to buy a License ( I hope MS as a company are not that cheap)   . Status Report is just a Table, with few thousands of records. I have a GUI to take the result as per date selection. But the case is, in the Query editor only I am facing this issue. No other parallel updates on the table is happening.

Comment: Does 'dbcc checkdb' return any errors?

Comment: It didn't give any error